# Enable an input in internet explorer using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom

I have this text input:

```js
function activateStep()
{ 
    document.getElementsByName("NOM")[0].removeAttribute('disabled');
}
```

```html
<input name="NOM" id="inputNom" disabled="disabled" type="text" />
<button onclick="activateStep()">Remove disability</button>
```

I add a click handler to a button to enable this input.

When I click into the button the attribute **disabled** were removed but the input still disabled!

I have this issue only in **IE**.

So how can I fix this?

Comment: Try `document.getElementsByName("NOM")[0].disabled = false;` instead

Comment: I tried it, but the same result in IE

Comment: @downvoter : please explain why you downvote my question !!

Comment: What version of IE? What does the button look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function activateStep()
{ 
document.getElementsByName("NOM")[0].disabled = false;
}
```

```html
<input name="NOM" id="inputNom" disabled="disabled" type="text" />
<button onclick="activateStep()">Remove disability</button>
```

[Click here](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_disabled.asp) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use this :

```
document.getElementsByName("NOM")[0].disabled = false;
```

instead removeAttribute

Example here : http://plnkr.co/edit/JT0dFWzM5FkJP0AzsTJH

Comment: I tested this solution. Works fine for me. Please don't forget to call the function.